# What's the lisp equivalent of System.exit(0)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Lets say I'm inside of multiple mapcar functions and I've found the successful terminating condition. I want to stop the execution of the rest of the code.

In java, I can do System.exit(0);

Does lisp have something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent of `System.exit()` doesn't really make sense in a REPL-oriented environment like Lisp; it may exist, but it won't, say, make your function return a value.

[`(return-from)`](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html#function-return-values) may do what you're looking for if your code is structured appropriately.

Comment: That's good enough from what i'm doing. I was inside a function with a double-nested mapcar with a lambda in each. By mentioning the name of the enclosing function, this did the trick.

Answer (score 15):

`MAPCAR`is not useful for iterating over data and exiting when a successful terminating condition is found.

Common Lisp provides `MAPC`, which is like `MAPCAR`, but does not accumulate the results. See also the function `MAP`.

Additionally Common Lisp provides numerous functions like `FIND`, `FIND-IF`, `FIND-IF-NOT`, ...

For flow control Common Lisp has `RETURN`, `RETURN-FROM`, `CATCH`and `THROW` and many others.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the appropriate solution in this case (use Dougal's answer for returning from nested loops/calls), but for completeness, the literal equivalent of `System.exit(0);` would be something like [Portable Exit](http://www.cliki.net/Portable%20Exit).

As you can see, it's completely different across implementations, because it's not part of the standard.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a helper that would work for most cases. It allows you to exit with a message or not and gives you a clear message in stdout:

```lisp
(defun _exit (&optional s)
  "Print and exit"
  (if s
     (error (format "_exit called - %s\n" s)) 
     (error "_exit called")
  )
)
```

Usage:

```
(_exit "testing 123")
```

Output before program exits:

```
> _exit called - testing 123
```

This will exit out of all functions and terminate the script.